# Visiting edges in a graph

Tags: algorithm, vector, graph, depth-first-search

I am using DFS algorithm and want to mark each edges as visited,An approach would be to look for the node and replace it with some sentinel but that would be costly,if i make an adjacency list to store the value corresponding to the node visited that would increase the lookup time,A matrix would consume a lot of space. what is the best algorithm to do so?

Comment: Do you need to record edges as being visited? In order for you to iterate through an edge twice, you would need to have gone through the same node twice. Keeping track of visited nodes should be simpler. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @A.Sokol i am visiting an edge and i need to record it so i would not visit that again,though i would if case like this exists 1->2 && 2->1.I need to print the order in which i visit the edge,so i need to store them .

Comment: so why don't you print it as you go along?

Comment: @CodingYoshi No,i dont want to,this is a subproblem,and need the order of edges to be stored.

Comment: i just need a better way to keep a track of the visited nodes with fast lookup time without using 2-D array.

Comment: use a dictionary or a hashtable

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yeah i thought that too but that would be a linear time look-up ,considering n elements in mth index of hash. i think this the best we could do without using matrix

Comment: No it will it would be O(1)

Comment: how could u elaborate please?let us say i have 2->3,5 and 3->4
hash= 2->3,5 and 3->4,Now if i want to lookup for 5,i would need to go linearly in 2.am i wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to mark edges as visited? DFS usually should only require marking vertices.

Comment: @RazimanT.V. DFS is basically graph traversal,i just need a way to traverse the graph without revisiting the edges,i could revisit the node in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to maintain a set of vertex pairs. E.g in Java `HashMap<Pair<Vertex, Vertex>>`. In Python, a `Set` of 2-element tuples.

The visiting of an edge occurs as you're enumerating the descendants of a new vertex just discovered and adding them to the DFS stack. If you're using a recursive DFS, then it's as you're making a recursive call on each descendant.  Here's the stack version:

```
dfs(graph)
  visitedVertices = \emptyset
  visitedEdges = \emptyset
  // Try all vertices as search roots
  for each vertex r in graph
    push r onto empty stack
    while notEmpty(stack)
      u = pop stack
      if u not in visitedVertices
        add u to visitedVertices
        foreach v such that u->v is in graph
          add (u,v) to visitedEdges // Visit the edge
          push v on stack
```

Having said that, I'm not sure why you want to do this. Correctly implemented DFS naturally traverses each edge exactly once. You can prove this to yourself by looking at the algorithm above. Visiting `(u,v)` is only possible if `u` has never been visited before.

Perhaps you have some other thread that's watching search progress or are actually adding other info to edges as you visit?

Comment: i want to make a graph euler circuit by redirecting edges and Fleury Algorithm is too complex(time consuming) for my constraint,i cannot afford removing an edge and applying dfs again to check if it was bridge or not.Dont you think above algorithm fails in a case when i try to visit the node more than once? and if 1->2 is marked an edge 2->1 is still possible because it is not been in marked edges but that would produce and undirected edge?

Comment: @idk I'm sorry I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Given a euler circuit which is distorted means edges have been rearranged,i want to make it euler circuit once again by redirecting edges which have been placed in wrong order to make the graph euler circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem.

In my code, a graph is represented as an adjacency list: graph[i] - is a list of nodes for given vertex i.

I made a set, in which I store visited edges. An edge is a tuple of size two.

**Depth-Search First**:

```
def visit_and_print_node(node):
    """Node visitor"""
    print(str(node))


def dsf_edges(graph, node_visitor_function=visit_and_print_node, starting_node=0):
    """
    Performs depth-first search algorithm on the edges of the graph.
    Note, here we visit edges, so it is OK for us to visit the same node more than once.
    """

    visited_edges = set()

    # next node to be visited is the last inserted element of the stack.
    stack = []

    next_nodes = graph[starting_node]

    node_visitor_function(starting_node)
    for node in next_nodes:
        stack.append((starting_node, node))

    while len(stack) > 0:
        visited_edge = stack.pop()
        if visited_edge in visited_edges:
            continue

        visited_node = visited_edge[1]

        # visit node
        node_visitor_function(visited_node)
        visited_edges.add(visited_edge)

        next_nodes = graph[visited_node]
        for node in next_nodes:
            if not (visited_node, node) in visited_edges:
                stack.append((visited_node, node))
```

If you would like to see other examples, BSF on edges (use queue instead of stack), or on nodes (visiting each node once), check [my git repository](https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/udacity-algorithms/blob/master/graph/graph.py):

Other useful links:

https://github.com/williamfiset/Algorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/williamfiset/algorithms/graphtheory/EulerianPathDirectedEdgesAdjacencyList.java

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MpoO2zA2l4